# preparing Virtualbox for windows 64bit

Tags: windows, virtualbox, 64-bit

I want to install Win8 on Virtualbox inside my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Vbox gave me no option for win8 64bit (only 32bit available)
when creating a new machine. Thus I googled...

On [this page of the virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html) I found:

**Warning:**

1. you should enable the I/O APIC
2. make sure that the VM uses the Intel networking device

Questions:

1. how do I (know if I did) enable I/O APIC?
2. how do I know if I have this Intel networking device?

Vbox version: 4.3.16 r95972

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on your VM in the Vbox manager and go to settings (1st option on the menu), you can confirm your I/O APIC setting (system->motherboard tab) and network device (in network in the advanced (click to open) section).

Comment: hi, 

Vbox settings -> System -> Enable IO APIC (checked)    

Vbox settings -> Network -> Advanced -> Adapter type -> Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop    

Seems that i satisfy both criteria. However when i try to create a new virtual machine on Vbox i still have only 32bit options. No 64bit system available!   

Thx...